# Using Euler's theorem and I still can't solve this question

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

let $n\in \Bbb Z$ suppose for every $q|n-1$ there is $a_q\in \Bbb Z_n^*$ that keeps equations $a_q^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ and $a_q^{\frac{n-1}{q}}\neq1 \pmod n$. proof that n is prime number.
can you help me?

I've been told to prove that $\Bbb Z_n^*$ is cyclic group and to calculate the order of it.

Thank you!

Comment: Nitpick.  What is $\mathbb Z_n^*$ if $n \le 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\ a^{n-1}\equiv 1\mod n\ $ implying $\ \gcd(a,n)=1\ $ hence there is some positive integer $\ k\ $ with $\ a^k\equiv 1\mod n\ $ because Euler's theorem states $\ a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\mod n\ $. The smallest positive integer $\ k\ $ with $\ a^k\equiv 1\mod n\ $ is called the order of $\ a\ $ modulo $\ n\ $, in the proof just called the "order".

If we have shown that $$a^k\equiv 1\mod n$$ does not hold for any positive integer $\ k<n-1\ $ , then we have shown that the order is $\ n-1\ $ , hence $\ n\ $ must be prime.

Now, suppose there is some $\ k<n-1\ $ with $\ a^k\equiv 1\mod n\ $ Then, $k$ is a proper factor of $n-1$ ($1$ is possible as well) , hence $\frac{n-1}{k}$ must have a prime factor $q$. So, we have some positive integer $\ m\ $ with $\ mkq=n-1\ $. This implies $\ k\mid \frac{n-1}{q}\ $, hence we would have $\ a^{\frac{n-1}{q}}\equiv 1\mod n\ $ , but this has been ruled out.

This is the easiest variant of the $\ n-1-$ method to prove the primality of some number $\ n\ $ , which only works if we can factor $\ n-1\ $ completely.

Comment: "then we have shown that the order is "  The order of what? The order of $a$?  If so you should specify that $a$ is relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: @fleablood  The more critical part is that I used a universal $a$ , but the statement assumes that for each $q$ there is some $a_q$.